# How to match the output shape of generator and the input shape of discriminator in GAN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am working on my first GANs model, I've followed Tensorflows official documentation using MNIST dataset. I've run it smoothly. I tried to replace MNIST with my own dataset, I've prepared it to match the same size as MNSIT: 28 * 28, it works.

However, my dataset is more complicated than MNIST so I tried to make the image size of my dataset larger: 512 * 512, but I keep getting errors related to input & output shape. I couldn't figure out the relationship between all these input and output shapes of the discriminator and generator. Assuming I want to change my dataset from 28 * 28 (MNSIT size) to y*y (custom size) which input/output shapes exactly I need to tune in these layers? and why? anyone could clarify this flow?

This is my code where I reshape my datasets to match MNIST size :

```
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
```

and here I normalize it :

```
train_images = (train_images - 127.5) / 127.5 # Normalize the images to [-1, 1]
```

This is the generator model where the output shape of the last layer indicating something 28 * 28 :

```
def make_generator_model():
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

model.add(layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256)))
assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 256) # Note: None is the batch size

model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 128)
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
assert model.output_shape == (None, 14, 14, 64)
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
assert model.output_shape == (None, 28, 28, 1)

return model
```

This is the discriminator model, where the input of the first layer indicating somehting 28 * 28 :

```
def make_discriminator_model():
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                 input_shape=[28, 28, 1]))
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

return model
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the formula for calculating output shape of Conv2DTranspose, which you can think of it as a learn-able way of upsampling:

```
# Padding==Same:
H = H1 * stride

# Padding==Valid
H = (H1-1) * stride + HF
```

where, `H = output size`, `H1 = input size`, `HF = height of filter`. From ["how-to-calculate-the-output-shape-of-conv2d-transpose"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26451/how-to-calculate-the-output-shape-of-conv2d-transpose)

So the the input&output shape of Conv2DTranspose should be:

```
(None, h1, h2, channels)
         ||
Conv2DTranspose(num_filters, (kernel_h1, kernel_h2), strides=(s1, s2), padding='same')
         ||
(None, h1*s1, h2*s2, num_filters)
```

Where None is batch_size

To just make the code **runnable**, you may just change the output shape of your first Dense Layer to `(8*8*256)` and repeat the `Conv2DTranspose->BatchNormalization->LeakyReLU` block until it becomes `(512*512)`for gray scale or `(512*512*3)` for RGB.
For discriminator, the only necessary change is only the `input_shape` in first layer. Since `Conv2D` with `padding='same'` doesn't change the shape of tensors.

**However**, the above changes doesn't guarantee a good result of your model. You really have to look into your task to decide how your model architecture should be.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was able to run my network successfully as you guided. But as you mentioned, to get better results, I still need to look for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

if your image shape is (64, 64, 3)
output of your generator must be (64, 64, 3) as input of discriminator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).